# Excel Dynamic Formula/Reference Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a dynamic reference within a formula; meaning the referenced workbook and subsequent sheet name can be changed and the appropriate data loaded.

[image]

I'm aware that a static formula reference could be done as follows:

```
=SUM('C:\Reports\[SOTDJ17.xlsx]Summary'!C10:C25)
```

but I want to be able to change the workbook name, and it will reference information from that particular workbook and change the data. The workbook name
is stored in B5 and the sheet is stored in B8. I thought I might be able to use
something simple like:

```
=SUM('C:\Reports\[B5]B8'!C10:C25)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a syntax error or something else I am missing?

(I should note that I am trying to reference a closed workbook)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this question has nothing to do with programming, and is thus off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Joe C - The excel-formula tag states "This tag is for Microsoft Excel questions where the question or answers are specifically about the structure, syntax, or output of an Excel formula."

I disagree with your assertion that my question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `Indirect()`:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("["&B5&"]"&B8&"!$C$10:$C$25"))`

Note that the workbook you're referring to must be open.

Comment: That formula works on open workbooks so thank you. Although it doesn't quite solve my problem (I want to reference a closed workbook) it has given me a place to start as I am not one to ask for copy-paste solutions.

Comment: @JSpeight Well, Afaik you must have the workbook open with `indirect()`. I don't know of another way to do what you are asking unless you can use VBA. (Even then you'd have to open the workbook, run the macro, then close it)

Comment: Yes, it would appear indirect() is not quite the answer I am looking for, however, it appears what I am trying to do is possible -  INDEX and VBA macros seem to be my best option so far but I am not a regular excel user so I think it will take a bit of trial and error.

Comment: @JSpeight it would be a new question to ask here. But to get you started, with your workbook  open start the macro recorder. Then open the workbook you want, go back to the main WB and run your Sum formula. Copy paste as values and close that second WB. Then stop the macro recorder and you'll have an outline of how the VBA would work.